# Какие кавычки использовать для цитаты на английском?

Tags: пунктуация, английский-язык

В русском языке принято использовать «ёлочки» в качестве основных кавычек и двойные «лапки» в качестве внутренних; в английском -- «английские двойные» и «английские одиночные» соответственно.

Какие кавычки следуют использовать в русском тексте для оформления цитаты на английском?

Например:

> Закон Маска гласит: "if things are not failing, you are not innovating enough".

Answer (score 2):

Правильно у вас написано. Можно так можно с елочками. Но не с одинарной кавычкой, в русском тексте это не принято.

В любом случае кавычки должны быть русские. Т. е. елочки и лапочки. Вы же в русский текст вставляете цитату, совершенно не важно, на каком языке она написана.

Впрочем, есть вариант в русском тексте иноязычную цитату вообще не закавычивать. Но эта идея имеет ограниченное употребление.

В отношении внутренних и внешних лапочек и елочек соответственно - не обольщайтесь, что "так принято". Встречал и обратную рекомендацию. А сам считаю вкусовщиной, по правилам внутренние и внешние должны быть **разного** рисунка. Остальное - не регламентируется. Тем более, если уровень вложенности более двух - я видел вполне реальную фразу с четырьмя вложенными "матрешками" их кавычек. Никаких елочек не напасешься.

И еще. Классические лапочки в русском наборе имеют разный рисунок для открывающей и закрывающей кавычки - как перевернутая и обычная запятая. Знак <"> - это принятая в компьютерном наборе замена. Но на эти тонкости давно рукой махнули.

Answer (score -1):

Закон Маска гласит: If things are not failing, you are not innovating enough, — «если что-то не удаётся, вам не хватает инноваций». Даже, если пояснение будет дано через точку, кавычки также неуместны, ибо текст верстается по русским законам.

Уточнение: русские используют два типа кавычек — « » и ˏˏˊˊ. Их можно найти в Таблице символов. На компьютерах и машинках имеется только упрощённый вариант западных кавычек (не запятые по рисунку, а прямые засечки) с верхним положением на строке. Об этом хорошо сказано и показано в книге, а кратко — на сайте А.Лебедева: http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/104/

Comment: В классических издания до 17 года - именно запятые. И на линотипах таковыми были. Засечки - это уже в пользу бедных, кажется при Софье Власьевне удумали.  А Артемий - тот еще авторитет в русском языке. Тут, правда, вопрос скорее типографский, но все равно Лебедев не истина в последней инстанции.

Comment: Посмотрите на кавычки в ПК, — именно форма засечек. При IrinaGL, как видите. Пишите Ответ, будьте полезны Автору вопроса, и он скажет спасибо. Насчет Лебедева как авторитета в русском языке я не говорил, не приписывайте. Он грамотный верстальщик и хорошо иллюстрирует то, что хочет донести.

Comment: *Посмотрите на кавычки в ПК* - Куда?! Я не знала, что ПК при царе Николае изобрели. Который первый.

Comment: Ох вы там добалуетесь, ох вы доизвлекаетесь...